# GCD of very large numbers

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

There are $3$ numbers $a$, $b$ and $n$ and I want to calculate gcd of $(a^n + b^n , |a - b| ) \bmod M$ ,where $1\le a, b,n \le 10^{12}$ and $M = 10^9 + 7$.

Comment: Does this come from http://www.codechef.com/AUG18B/problems/GCDMOD ?

Comment: I thought Hackerrank, due to that $M$.